# Average time to process requests with QueryDSL JPA

Tags: jpa, aggregate-functions, querydsl

I'm developing a report on a project that involves handling various types of requests.
Hence, the request entity has type, closingDate and creationDate fields.

I need, grouping by type, to calculate the average time to process requests,
i.e.: avg(closingDate-creationDate)

Having used QueryDSL JPA for all other queries, I wish I could do the same for this report as well, but I was not able to find a solution.

I have tried to use **DateTimeExpression** but I didn't figure out which method would work for me.

I've also tried to use the following statement in the query:

```
request.closingDate.castToNum(Double.class).subtract(request.creationDate.castToNum(Double.class)).avg().
```

However I have the feeling **castToNum** is not the right method to do so, because the numerical result is quite different from what I expected.

I've also looked over the net and here as well, but all the answers I found were out of date.
I looked for some solution on QueryDSL documentation, without success.

So, my questions are: Is it feasible to use QueryDSL JPA to make this calculation on the query using aggregate functions? And How?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to make it work properly:

I used the following statement in the query:

`query = query.select((Expressions.numberTemplate(Double.class, "{0} - {1}", request.closingDate, request.creationDate).avg()) ...`

I write it here so it could be helpful to someone else.
Of course I'm grouping the results by request type field.
The result will be the average time difference between the two dates, expressed in nanoseconds (at least this is what I got).
To get minutes or hours it'll be needed to make some calculation.